# doxygen 1.8.3 subpage: missing space

Tags: doxygen

Running doxygen 1.6.2 there's no problem but if I run 1.8.3 (on win7) I have a problem with a missing space.

**The code:**

```
/** \mainpage FEAST Overview

Chapter \subpage tutorial_page - Go here to work through the calculator
example that shows how to create a simple Web-Service driven application
from scratch.
```

*/

/** \page tutorial_page Tutorials

```
This chapter contains a list of tutorials and examples that introduce the most
important features of FEAST.
```

*/

**The result:**

```
ChapterTutorials - Go here to work through the calculator example that shows how to create a simple Web-Service driven application from scratch.
```

Between **Chapter** and **Tutorials** there's no space.
Is it a bug ?

Comment: Well, all the documentation of the project is messed up with doxy 1.8.3, not only a missing space. I've just joined the company so the doxy files are not mine, but they look good... I really don't understand: it seems to be a bug but I cannot find someone with the same problem on internet.

Comment: Ok, using 1.8.1 as 1.8.2 is even worse.